# MultiValueDictKeyError in Django trying to change profile pic

Tags: python, django, django-views

i ve got this . I just want to change profile informations in that request i tried to change first_name and last_name. Here is my views.py. Check my code and tell me what's wrong . I need a solution for my error, i didnt try anything because i dont understand and know django very well

And thank you !

**views.py**

```py
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if not request.POST['first_name'] == '' and not request.POST['first_name'] == request.user.first_name:
            if not request.POST['last_name'] == '' and not request.POST['last_name'] == request.user.last_name:
                if not request.FILES['image'] == '':
                    User = request.user
                    User.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
                    User.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
                    User.save()
                    User.profile.image = request.FILES['image']
                    User.profile.save()
                    return redirect('profile')
                else:
                    User = request.user
                    User.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
                    User.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
                    User.save()
                    return redirect('profile')

            else:
                User = request.user
                User.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
                User.save()
                return redirect('profile')
        elif not request.POST['last_name'] == '' and not request.POST['last_name'] == request.user.last_name:
            if not request.POST['first_name'] == '' and not request.POST['first_name'] == request.user.first_name:
                if not request.FILES['image'] == '':
                    User = request.user
                    User.profile.image = request.FILES['image']
                    User.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
                    User.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
                    User.save()
                    User.profile.save()
                    return redirect('profile')
                else:
                    User = request.user
                    User.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
                    User.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
                    User.save()
                    return redirect('profile')

            else:
                User = request.user
                User.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
                User.save()
                return redirect('profile')
        elif not request.FILES['image'] == '':
            if not request.POST['last_name'] == '' and not request.POST['last_name'] == request.user.last_name:
                if not request.POST['first_name'] == '' and not request.POST['first_name'] == request.user.first_name:
                    User = request.user
                    User.profile.image = request.FILES['image']
                    User.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
                    User.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
                    User.save()
                    User.profile.save()
                    return redirect('profile')
                else:
                    User = request.user
                    User.profile.image = request.FILES['image']
                    User.profile.save()
                    User.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
                    User.save()
                    return redirect('profile')

            else:
                User = request.user
                User.profile.image = request.FILES['image']
                User.profile.save()
                return redirect('profile')
        else:
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        return render(request, 'profile.html')
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode (please copy the code in the question), *not* images of code/exceptions.

Comment: I wrote the code please check it and tell me what should i change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to check if `request.FILES` contains a key, you do *not* check with:

```
if not request.FILES['image'] == '':
    # …
```

You check if an element is in the `QueryDict` with:

```
if 'image' in request.FILES:
    # …
```

Note that in order to post both files and data, in the `<form>` the `enctype="…"` should be set to `multipart/form-data`:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    …
</form>
```

Furthermore please do *not* branch that much, you can make a view that looks like:

```
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.user
        if 'first_name' in request.POST:
            user.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        if 'last_name' in request.POST:
            user.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        if 'image' in request.FILES:
            profile = user.profile
            profile.image = request.FILES['image']
            profile.save()
        user.save()
        return redirect('profile')
    else:
        # …
```

You furthermore might want to make use of a [**`Form`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/) or even a [**`ModelForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) to make rendering the form, validating the input, and updating the record more convenient.